# Please reopen my question

Tags: support, reopen-request

[Identify this excerpt](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/identify-this-excerpt)

This question was initially closed as off-topic.  But I've edited it and made it into an on-topic one.  I want this to be reopened, but I can't cast my vote.

Can anyone else please reopen my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't just edit the question, you completely changed it. Please don't use the edit feature to completely rewrite a question. If you want to turn an off-topic question to an on-topic one, do small changes that keep similarities between the old (off-topic) question, and the new (on-topic) one.

You just need to start a whole new question.

Comment: So, are you saying my question will **not** be reopened?

Comment: @Yubin-chan, so you are saying that you did **not** read what other users and I wrote?

Comment: no, I did........